# Google Identity Toolkit failing to sign-up new user: Error code: Internal error encountered

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

New users trying to setup logins that aren't @google.com are hitting issues using Google Identity Toolkit. This has been working fine for a long time so not sure what's up. Looks like this:

[image]

In the console seeing a 500 error coming back when calling this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/setAccountInfo?key=<key>
```

POST data:

```
{"email":"nlckeweo@sharklasers.com","displayName":"test","password":"password"}
```

API response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: @bojeil any insight on this issue?

Comment: I reported it to someone at Google and they have rolled out a fix. I've verified that the issue is resolved at my end. You may want to verify it too.

Comment: You are my hero @DFB! Just verified everything is working again!